# Check if argument passed to node C++ addon is Infinity or NaN

Tags: c++, node.js, node.js-addon

How do you check if an argument passed directly to a node C++ addon (not via a JS wrapper) is NaN or +/-Infinity?

I tried `frexp(arg[0]->NumberValue(), &exponent)` with the intent of checking if the exponent is 2047 (how JS represents NaN and Infinity), but evidently `Local<Value>->NumberValue()` obscures the double and changes the exp value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For C++11 the reply is

```
std::isinf(x) || std::isnan(x)
```

Comment: std::isinf(x) not isinfo